# Node Js file upload error using multer. File is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, multer

I am trying to upload an image file in an express endpoint using multer but it is not working. I keep getting the 500 unexpected field error. I need to be able to read the image from the route

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/uploads/images',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() +
            path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fieldSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 } });


/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/items/test:
 *  post:
 *      summary: add a new item
 *      tags: [Item]
 *      description: use to add a new item to a specific vendor
 *      requestBody:
 *          content:
 *              multipart/form-data:
 *                  schema:
 *                      type: object
 *                      properties:
 *                          fileName:
 *                              type: string
 *                              format: binary
 */
 
 router.post('/test', upload.single('featuredImage'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.file)
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fileName` should correspond to the field name given in `multer` reference, i.e. `featuredImage`, hence the error

try replacing it:

```
 *                      properties:
 *                          featuredImage:
 *                              type: string
 *                              format: binary
```